# Unable to use twilio API

Tags: java, intellij-idea, twilio

When I want to run the Java code of the twilio API with IntelliJ, it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException".
```

I have already added the twilio-7.14.5.jar to the module's dependencies.

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

public class main
{
     public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC935209d3c44660b4a550e3380249857a";
     public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "42bcd28e23344404c737eb3499d2a747";

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
         Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+13195120377"),
            new PhoneNumber("+13193204088"),
            "The temperature is over heat now!").create();
     }
}
```

[screen shot for the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfyTH.png)

Comment: You need to add the dependent jars that twilio uses to work with json. Add the jar for JsonMappingException in your classpath as Runtime depenedency

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all the dependencies used by Twilio 7.4.15 version. The maven repository lists all the required dependencies http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio/7.14.5